# can't get swagger working (wildfly 9)

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly, swagger

I found swagger and swagger-ui and I like the approach. I already managed to get it working at least on Spring boot.
Now I would like to integrate swagger in a Java EE application running on wildfly 9.
Unfortunately this doesn't work at all. Swagger is really poor documented.

What is necessary to get it working? I follwed the instructions from the official swagger documentation at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X.

This is my swagger dependency in build.gradle:

```
compile 'io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:1.5.4'
```

This is my JAX-RS application class:

```
public class SmamblRestApiApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();

    public SmamblRestApiApplication() {
        initClasses();
    }

    private void initSwagger() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setTitle("SmamblV1");
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/rest/v1");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.myapp.api.v1.rest");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }

    private void initClasses() {
        //--- Api Endpoints --------------------------------------
        classes.add(RegistrationApi.class);
        classes.add(MigrationApi.class);
        classes.add(PhoneNumberApi.class);
        classes.add(UserResourceApi.class);
        classes.add(MonitoringApi.class);
        classes.add(PingApi.class);
        classes.add(PublicUserResource.class);


        //--- Filters --------------------------------------------
        classes.add(ApiExceptionMapper.class);
        classes.add(SecurityRolesFilter.class);

        //--- Swagger --------------------------------------------
        classes.add(ApiListingResource.class);
        classes.add(SwaggerSerializers.class);
    }


    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }
}
```

And I even annotated one method with a swagger annotation:

```
@Path("private/user")
@RolesAllowed({UserRole.USER})
@NoCache
@Api
public class UserResourceApi {

    @Inject
    UserFacade userFacade;

    @RolesAllowed(UserRole.ADMIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @GET
    @ApiOperation("test")
    public List<UserResource> getAllUsers() {
        return userFacade.findAllUsers();
    }
// ...
```

When trying to reach the swagger.json as desribed in the documentation above, an empty file is returned (no 404 or s.th., so I believe something is working but doesn't output anything).
What can I do?

Btw. can anyone explain me the difference between the com.wordnik and io.swagger packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be ok (I have a similar configuration working with WildFly). But, I don't see the `initSwagger` method called in your code. Maybe the problem is only that the method is not being called.

Comment: Oh no I forgot to call my own method. This is so embarassing :-D Thanks for your hint!